# Google Apps Script sync with oracle

Tags: oracle, google-apps-script

I am trying to fetch the data from Oracle by Google Apps Script, I am able to fetch the data by simple queries like

```
Select * from EMP_TABLE
```

and

```
Select * from EMP_TABLE where EMP_NAME = "Dhananjay"
```

But I am not able to fetch the  data by below query

```
Select * from EMP_TABLE where EMP_ID = 1100
```

in above case all other relational operators are working fine but equal to is not working for any numerical field.

Need help on fetching data from oracle by Google Apps script.
statement that I am using is :

```
 var rs = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM EMP_TABLE WHERE EMP_ID = 1100');
```

Comment: "is not working" is too vague.  Please describe *how* it does not work.   Error?  Empty result set?  Hangs?  Please confirm that you have checked for the existence of a record in the EMP_TABLE where EMP_ID = 1100.

Comment: Yes, record is present in the table, I am able to get the proper result by using command prompt or SQL plus. In case of Google script i am only getting the headers not values